# How to populate recyclerview with data from parse server?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, parse-server

Is it possible to retrieve all the data present in a specific class in the parse server in the form of a news feed similar to facebook using recyclerView?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

in order to do it you need to do the following:

1. I recommend you to use [Parse SDK for android](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Android). You can read the docs [in here](http://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/) . This SDK will make your life easy with performing all CRUD operations in front of your parse server instance. So the thing that you need to do is to execute query on your class like the following (taken from parse server docs):

```html
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("<YOUR_CLASS_NAME>");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + scoreList.size() + " scores");
        } else {
            Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

From the code above you can see that we first create a query object on  class and then use **findInBackground** in order to retrieve all objects.

2. Inside that findInBackground callback what you need to do is to iterate on all results and map them to your recyclerView adapter and finally refresh it and see the results

From the answer above you can see that's its pretty simple task if you use Parse Android SDK. As much as I know there is no out of the box solution that will create recyclerView from parse query results.